# Apache shiro - How to support multiple user types with individual database tables

Tags: java, spring, authentication, shiro

I am working on a web project using `Java` / `Spring` / `Apache Shiro`,
there are 3 different user types in 3 individual db tables, 2 user types login from web page, 1 user type login from mobile.

I have implemented a `Realm` which extends `AuthorizingRealm`, but it seems difficult for me to provide a single Restful API to let the 3 user types to login.

**My current thought is:**

Define a new token class which extends `UsernamePasswordToken`, and add a new field `accountType`, when user login first check account type param, then decide which table to query, and use combination of `accountType` and `username` as `Principal`.

**My question is:**

1. Would the above thought work? Or how I should improve that?
2. How should I define the `loginUrl` for 3 different user, especial for mobile client, it should be a `json result` other than a url, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have kind solved the problem.

Here is what I did:

- Implement `UsernamePasswordToken`, and add a accountType field.
- Use `accountType:username` as principal. Need to override relevant methods.
- When login, user need to provide the `accountType` parameter.
- When query db, according to accountType, query different table.